# trying to get a proper names(list) output

Tags: r, list, apply

I'm trying to split a 2 level deep list of characters into a 1 level list using a suffix. 
More precisely, I have a list of genes, each containing  6 lists of probes corresponding to 6 bins. The architecture looks like :

```
feat_indexed_probes_bin$HSPB6$bin1

 [1] "cg14513218" "cg22891287" "cg20713852" "cg04719839" "cg27580050" "cg18139462" "cg02956481" "cg26608795" "cg15660498" "cg25654926" "cg04878216"
```

I'm trying to get a list "bins_indexed_probes" with the following architecture :

`bins_indexed_probes$HSPB6_bin6` containing the same probes so I can pass it to my map-reducing function.

I tried many solutions such as `melt()`, for loop, etc but I can't figure how to perform a double nested loop ( on genes and on bins) and get a list output with only 1 level depth.

For the moment, my `func` to do so is the following :

```
create_map <- function(indexes = feat_indexed_probes_bin, binlist = c("bin1", "bin2", "bin3", "bin4", "bin5", "bin6"), genes = features) {
  map <- list()

  ret <- lapply(binlist, function(bin) {
      lapply(rownames(features), function(gene) {
      map[[paste(gene, "_", bin, sep = "")]] <- feat_indexed_probes_bin[[gene]][[bin]]
      tmp_names <<- paste(gene, "_", bin, sep = "")
      return(map)
    })
    names(map) <- tmp_names
    rm(tmp_names)
  })
  return(ret)
}
```

it returns:

```
[[6]][[374]]
  GDF10_bin6 
"cg13565300" 

[[6]][[375]]
NULL

[[6]][[376]]
[[6]][[376]]$HNF1B_bin6
[1] "cg03433642" "cg09679923" "cg17652435" "cg03348978" "cg02435495" "cg02701059" "cg05110178" "cg11862993" "cg09463047"


[[6]][[377]]
[[6]][[377]]$GPIHBP1_bin6
[1] "cg01953797" "cg00152340"
```

instead, I would expect something like

```
$GPIHBP1_bin1

"cg...." "cg...."

...

$GPIHBP1_bin6

"someotherprobe"

$someothergene_bin1

"probe" "probe"
...
```

I hope I'm being clear, and since this is my first time asking question, I already apologise if I didn't follow the stackoverflow protocol.

Thank you already for reading me

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a (small) sample of your dataset with `dput()`, so that your code and problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a nested `lapply` with extract, `[[`, and `setNames` calls, all wrapped in `do.call` using `c` to bind return elements together.

```
bins_indexed_probes <- do.call(c,
    lapply(1:6, function(i)
           setNames(lapply(feat_indexed_probes_bin, `[[`, i),
                           paste0(names(feat_indexed_probes_bin), "_bin", i))
          )
)

# RE-ORDER ELEMENTS BY NAME                 
bins_indexed_probes <- bins_indexed_probes[sort(names(bins_indexed_probes))]
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/MHK87473)

Comment: thanks for answering. I will try as soon as i get home.